# Change variable group value of Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Variable Group in Azure Pipeline(below attached),
[image]

I want to change the value of isPOS to False through below mentioned conditions,

```
$angular = (Get-Content "$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/amaze-commerce/angular.json" -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json
   
   if ($angular.defaultProject -ne "ecomm-ac-ecomm"){
    // Please add your code here
   }
```

Can you please guide me to change the Variable group value and i want to use the same in Release Pipeline.

Comment: Hello, haven't got your latest news. Is there any updates on this issue? Please check whether Assael Azran's answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the value of a variable group use [Azure DevOps Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0).

An example of how to update a variable group:

**Variablegroups - Get Variable Groups - filtered by {groupName}**

```
$pat ="<your-tfs-security-token>"
$read = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$pat"))

$variableGroupName = "Check for angular.json"

$variableGroupId = ((Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{'Authorization' = "Basic $read" } -Uri "https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?groupName=${variableGroupName}").Value).id
```

**Variablegroups - Update**

```
    $body =@"
    {
      "variables": {
        "isPOS": {
          "value": $false
        }
      },
      "type": "Vsts",
      "name": "${variableGroupName}",
      "description": "Updated variable group"
    }
"@

    $response= (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/${variableGroupId}?api-version=5.0-preview.1"  -Method Put  -Headers @{'Authorization' = "Basic $read" }  -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body)
```

Comment: thank you very much for you code which helps me to work with no issue.

Comment: @sanjai https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers